How much information is encoded in a ball on a field?
Consider a soccer ball placed on a planar field of finite dimension (just like a soccer field). How much information can be realistically encoded  in the position of the ball on the field?

This question is ill-defined. Is the field marked? Are we allowed to use measuring devices? If so, what is the precision of the devices? Are we allowed to use the rotational orientation of the ball in the encoding? And so on...

Depends on many things which you don't specify, as the previous comment elaborates. In other words: To compute the Shannon entropy, you have to give us a probability distribution.

Is this a round-about way of asking with what precision the location of a ball can be determined by real-world, technological means? If so, then it's an engineering question, and there potentially are many possible answers depending on what, exactly is meant by "soccer ball" and "planar field" and, on how much time is allowed for each measurement and, on whether or not the measuring device is allowed to touch the ball or, if not, how close it is allowed to approach the ball and, on various environmental considerations and, on etc. and etc. and etc.

Just a rough estimate. Let's take a standard soccer field dimensions $100~\text{yard} \times 50~\text{yard}$. Assuming a ball can be placed anywhere within this field with a $\delta x = 1~mm$ precision in position,- there's a total of $n\cdot m = 4.2 × 10^9~mm^2$ field "slots" where a ball can go.
If a ball position on the field probability is uniform (the same for all slots), Shannon entropy reduces to $$ H(n,m) = −\log_2\left(\frac {1}{n\cdot m}\right) = −\log_2\left(\frac {1}{4.2 × 10^9}\right) \approx 32~\text{bits}/\text{position}$$
of compressed information per ball position on the field (or roughly $4 ~\text{bytes}$). And whole soccer field encodes about $17~\text{GB}$ of position data.
Results can vary when changing position precision, field size, or using non-uniform field position probabilities.

If I understand correctly, this question reduces to "how much information can be stored in a point in a plane?" My answer would be: the amount of information that can be stored in a point at rest in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is precisely the dimension of the space: $n$ (in your case, $n=2$ since your field is planar). That is to say, you can obtain 2 pieces of independent information from the position of the point in the field.
If the point is not at rest, then you can obtain even more information, although it will now vary with time. At any given instant $t$, the coordinates of the point would give two independent pieces of information. Nonetheless, your point can now have a velocity as well, and the method of encoding information in its velocity would have to be defined by you. For instance, I could assign a number from 1 to 4 to the directions in which the point could move (North, South, East and West). However, what happens if the ball is moving Northwest? Perhaps an ergodic approach like that of QM would be useful, since the information encoded in the movement of the ball would be a superposition of several independent pieces of information (analogous to the superposition of several bound states of an electron when it's not being measured). The same applies for acceleration and the higher derivatives of position with respect to time.
Therefore, as I see it you can encode an infinite amount of information in a moving ball, but realistically this would require you to force the ball to follow some utterly complex path (unless the movement were periodic, then your information would be repeated every 2 or 4 derivations, depending on whether you choose to ignore signs or not).
